# How to get information, if plant species occur at specific coordinates by using shapefiles in R

Tags: r, coordinates, geospatial, shapefile

I want to create a tables using R that contain the information, if plant species occur at specific points (coordinates). Therefore, I want to use shapefiles, containing the distribution of several specific plant species. My output has to be a table, that for every point/coordinate indicate the presence of every plant species as 1 and the absence as 0.

First, I read in my first shapefile and the CVS table, containing the coordinates I need:

```
plant <- shapefile ('plant.shp')
birds<-read.csv2("bird_Coordinates.csv")
```

Next, I extract the coordinates, save them in a dataframe and project the points over the distribution shapefile:

```
lats <- birds$lat
lons <- birds$lon
pts <- data.frame(x=lons,y=lats)
coordinates(pts) <- ~x+y
proj4string(pts) <- proj4string(plant)
```

When I now plot the shapefile and the coordinates, I see the shape of the plant distribution and two red points, which indicate that two of my about 60 points are within this distribution:

```
plot(plant)
points(pts, pch=20, col='red')
```

Next, I try to use `over`, to associate the points to the distribution. Here I used two different ways:

1.

```
over(pts, plant)$admin
cbind.data.frame(pts, plant=over(pts, plant)$admin)
```

Resulting in the warning message: Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : Arguments imply differing numbers of rows: 64, 0

2.

```
plantsp <- !is.na(over(pts, as(plant, "SpatialPolygons")))
pts$plant <- over(pts, plant)$Unit_Name
```

Resulting the the warning message: Error in validObject(.Object) : invalid class “SpatialPointsDataFrame”: number of rows in data.frame and SpatialPoints don't match

So, both possibilities fail and I do not know what I did wrong. I know, that for this distribution range, only two points are inside the range, is the the source of the trouble? And how may I fix this? I would be so thankful, if anyone could tell me, how to get this cvs Table, containing the presence/absense information for the distribution ranges for every point!

Comment: Could you share your data so that we can test out solutions? Failing that, can you provide a minimal reproducible example (see this post for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r60fr2tblaqslzb/AAANCgZTHuFBCYuGMBuo1gOFa?dl=0
Do you have access to the data with this link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this problem will be easier to solve with `rgdal` or `sf` (I recommend learning `sf`, as it's newer, but for now I'm more familiar with `rgdal` which is why I've used it here).

Load `rgdal` (which also loads `sp`, which we'll need):

```
library("rgdal")

# Open the shapefile and copy the projection,
# which we'll need for the bird data

plant <- readOGR(".", "N_columbiana")
wgs84 <- proj4string(plant)

# open the bird data and make a copy for when we change to
# spatialPointsDataFrame

birds <- read.csv2("bird_Coordinates.csv") 
birds_data <- birds

# Correct the order of long/lat so the coordinates are correct
birds <- birds[, c("lon", "lat")]
birds <- sp::SpatialPointsDataFrame(birds, birds_data,
                                    proj4string = CRS(wgs84))

# plot to make sure it's worked
plot(plant)
plot(birds, add = TRUE)

# the @data slot is now a data frame for the shapefile
# make all in_plant 0 by default before we subset
birds@data$in_plant <- 0

# Get the specimenID of those birds within the plant boundary
# the birds[plant, ] does the subsetting
# the @data$SpecimenID returns just the specimenID
in_plant <- birds[plant, ]@data$SpecimenID
birds@data$in_plant[in_plant] <- 1

# check it's all worked
plot(plant)
plot(birds[birds@data$in_plant == 1, ], add = TRUE)
```

If you want to extract just the data you can assign it to another object:

```
new_data <- birds@data
new_data
#     SpecimenID      lat         lon in_plant
#  1           1 46.06667    7.600000        0
#  2           2 46.60134    9.965973        0
#  3           3 46.02360    7.748607        0
#  4           4 46.60134    9.965973        0
#  5           5 46.91833   13.873611        0
#  ...
#  48         48 40.01861 -105.278056        1
#  49         49 40.02977 -105.581228        1
#  50         50 47.05917   13.615556        0
```

Comment: I edited the question to answer that point: save `birds@data` to another object if you want to use it within R. If you want to save it, as `csv` for example, use `write.csv(birds@data, file = "birds_matched.csv")`

Comment: @Alice No worries. Will you accept/upvote the answer so that others see the solution worked.

Comment: Done. Thank you again.